# Laravel Dingo API multiple versions when strict mode is false?

Tags: php, laravel, dingo-api

I dont know if this possible, but is possible to have multiple versions of [Dingo API](https://github.com/dingo/api) so for example:

I can use:

```
api.example.com/v1/request
api.example.com/v2/request
api.example.com/v3/request
```

and still be able to search via the web browser

Edit:

Try creating a middleware to try to set the setting depending on the request. Like this:

```
 $request_url = $request->getRequestUri();
 $request_url = explode("/", $request_url);
 $current_version = array_filter($request_url);
 Config::set('api.version', $current_version[1]);
```

But still nothing, any one has an idea?

Comment: What's the problem? What's the error message? What are you getting and what did you expect?